# How can I change svg text tag X Y when this tag load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

svg code is here

```js
    function calculateXY(text, angle) {
        text.setAttribute('x',111.5 * Math.cos(angle) + 142.5);
        text.setAttribute('y',111.5 * Math.sin(angle) + 142.5);
    }
```

```html
<svg width="285" height="285" class="pie-svg" >
        <g>
            <circle class="pie-1" r="111.5" cx="142.5" cy="142.5" stroke="#303840" stroke-dasharray="175 525" transform="rotate(0, 142.5,142.5)"></circle>
            <text class="pie-text-percent" onload="calculateXY(this, 45)" fill="#ffffff" transform="rotate(90, 142.5,142.5)">25%</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

I want to change text xy when this tag load, but it not working, what can I do?

Comment: Which value contains `text`?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed `text.setAttribute` to `text.setAttributeNS` and it kind of works. However the text falls outside the svg canvas and you can see it because I've set the svg overflow to visible. **Now I need to understand where do you need the text.**

```js
function calculateXY(text, angle) {
        text.setAttributeNS(null,'x',111.5 * Math.cos(angle) + 142.5);
        text.setAttributeNS(null,'y',111.5 * Math.sin(angle) + 142.5);
    }
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;overflow:visible}
circle{fill:none}
```

```html
<svg width="285" height="285" class="pie-svg" >
        <g>
            <circle class="pie-1" r="111.5" cx="142.5" cy="142.5" stroke="#303840" stroke-dasharray="175 525" transform="rotate(0, 142.5,142.5)"></circle>
            <text class="pie-text-percent" onload="calculateXY(this, 45)" fill="#000" transform="rotate(90, 142.5,142.5)">25%</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: firefox won't dispatch onload on text elements.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand you. The  code example is working on Firefox. Can you provide a link where I can read about this?